# Vim close window without closing buffer

Tags: vim

How do I close a window or unsplit without deleting the buffer?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you want to edit another buffer in the window, just use `:edit` / `:buf`. The current buffer will be replaced, and remains in the buffer list (i.e. it shows up in `:ls`).

If you want to close the windows split, use `:close`. The `:quit` command will work, too, but has the side effect of closing Vim when this is the last window.

In order to leave buffers that have changes, you need

```
:set hidden
```

If you know how Vim deals with buffers, this is a recommended option that many users have set.

Answer (score 103):

A window is a viewport on a buffer. In vim to manage windows it is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> the leading command, that you can follow with several options (in bold those that answer to your question):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>v</kbd>: Opens a new vertical split

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd>: Opens a new horizontal split

**<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd>: Closes a window but keeps the buffer**

**<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>o</kbd>: Closes other windows, keeps the active window only**

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>right arrow</kbd>: Moves the cursor to the window on the right

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>r</kbd>: Moves the current window to the right

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>=</kbd>: Makes all splits equal size

Then, you need to switch the buffers in the windows:

`:ls` lists all opened buffers

`:b5` switches to your 5th buffer

Finally, to open all buffers in a vertical split, use: `:vertical sball`.
Very useful when you open multiple files as buffers after a grep:

```
grep -rno --exclude-dir={dir1,dir2,dir3} "searchterm" *
vim $(!! -l)
```

For more info, see the doc: [vimdoc.sourceforge.net](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html)

Answer (score 7):

Vim windows are closed using `:q`.

However, if you don't have another window open, it will exit from Vim. If you do have another window to switch to, only the current window is closed, and buffer remains open. You may need to `set hidden`.

To close a buffer, you would need to do `:bdelete`.

You can check if your buffer is open or not by using `:buffers`.

Comment: but I found that deletes the buffer too, or is because of I'm using windows gvim?

Comment: @Rnet - It shouldn't. What does :buffers show after you use :q?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers, well that buffer name is not listed there, strange. I had been tinkering with plugins, that could have caused a problem.

Comment: @Rnet - You could start as `gvim -u NONE` and verify it works there. If it does, I would start with `gvim --noplugin` and verify again. That way you know if it's a plugin or your own .vimrc.

Comment: Alternatively you could try `:set verbose=1|map q`

Comment: Thank you for listing `:bdelete`