# How do I close a buffer while keeping the window open?

Tags: vim

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087724/vim-close-window-without-closing-buffer) is related, but I would like to achieve the opposite. My vim screen is vertically split in 2. I have opened several files in the right window. When I close the file with `:q` or `:bdelete` the right window closes. Is it possible to have a behaviour where the right window stays open and shows the last open file in that window?

Comment: Thanks @dlmeetei `:b#|bd#` works.

Comment: You don't "open several files in the right window".

Comment: @romainl are you referring to the [Vimdoc](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#window) description _"a window is a viewport on a buffer"_? Intuitively I thought these were files open. I find it confusing that the screen resizes itself when I close a file. I would like to maintain the vertical split and start editing a new file in the right screen.

Comment: I mean that files are not and can't be associated with windows.

Comment: @romainl , could you please explain why files "can't be associated with windows."?

Comment: When you open a "file", a "buffer" is created and added to the "buffer list". Because that list is global it's impossible to associate a buffer and a "window" and therefore a file and a window. The right way to think about windows is as "viewport": you create a new viewport through which you can look at any given buffer.